# Validate Excel imported data

Tags: java, apache-poi, validation

I am importing an excel sheet with 30 columns using Apache POI framework. I am reading each cell and inserting it into database.

I need to validate each of these columns for different conditions, other than using multiple if else conditions and calling different methods for each columns is there any other way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have less experience with java. There could be multiple ways to solve your problem. However I have used Strategy Pattern to design a common validation class which can be used for different type of items without ugly if-else block. Though I had to create separate validation method for different type of fields, but I feel this is better than having lot of if else block.

```
interface IValidator<T> {
  boolean validate(T field);
}

class SomeFieldOne<T> implements IValidator<T> {
  public boolean validate(T field) {
    print("SomeFieldOne validation");
    return true; // return true/false based on validation
  }
}

class SomeFieldTwo<T> implements IValidator<T> {
  public boolean validate(T field) {
    print("SomeFieldTwo validate");
    return true; // return true/false based on validation
  }
}

class Context {
  private IValidator validator;

  public Context(IValidator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
  }

  public boolean validate(String field) {
    return this.validator.validate(field);
  }
}

public class TestValidation {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Context context;

    context = new Context(new SomeFieldOne());
    print(context.validate("some field one"));

    context = new Context(new SomeFieldTwo());
    print(context.validate("some field two"));

    // test other fields ....
    // .........
  }
}
```

Comment: A review and improvement of this answer is available on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/35491/validation-class-to-avoid-ugly-if-else-blocks)

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks for your answer. So I tried this approach by creating a Map of column name and the validator object in it, so select the appropriate validator class. However while doing so, I am unable to call another function written in an EJB. As per my limited understanding of EJB, I understand that this issue is because I am creating the objects myself and pushing it to the Map. Do you have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @coder I don't have much knowledge using EJB, but I suggest you go through the stack trace and try to find out what exactly is causing the problem. If you still unable to figure out, I think you could ask a different question in SO with the error message.